# How Can I get setTypeFace in floatingActionButton?

Tags: android

Iam trying to add textView.SetTypeFace in floatingactionbutton but iam not getting any suggetions

Comment: Show your code, so that other people could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The floating Action Button is a button Decends from Imageview, so you can's add text To that. 
you can set the floating action button image using setImageDrawable(Drawable)

For more information you can refer : [Floating Action Button Expalained](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html)

Comment: can i set SetTypeFace for labelText for FloatingActionButton